# how to skip MongoError: E11000 duplicate key to continue creating

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am wondering how I can let the process continue creating objects after it runs into a duplicate key error - to the next record - currently when it runs into a dup key it stops creating the rest of the things in the document

the dup key it is hitting is _id (unique index)

currently I am just catching the err in a try catch block but I'm not sure what I can do from here

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`insertMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.insertMany) with opion `ordered: false`

> Excluding Write Concern errors, ordered operations stop after an error, while unordered operations continue to process any remaining write operations in the queue.